# count of unique orders by product id or sku magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to show how count of unique orders(not qty sold, but count of orders).
Also which means exclude multiple orders from same customer ID in magento

Ex:
We wanted to know the how many times the product is sold.
If customer purchases the same product 2 or 3 or 4, the result should be 1

customer_name     product_sku    ordered

test1              rasp123       2

test1              rasp123       1

test2              rasp123       1

test3              rasp123       5

Result should be product sku(rasp123) is sold 3 times

Thanks in advance help me a great.

Comment: explain with one small example

Comment: Thanks for the response please find the updated question above.

Answer (score 2):

Find below code

```
$salesModel=Mage::getModel("sales/order");
$salesCollection = $salesModel->getCollection();
$data=array();
foreach($salesCollection as $order)
{
    $name=$order->getCustomerName();
    $id=$order->getIncrementId();
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $data[$name][$item->getSku()][$id]=$item->getQtyOrdered();
    }
}

  /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        exit;*/
```

Find array structure

```
Array
(
    [Mosses Akizian] => Array
        (
            [abl007] => Array
                (
                    [100000049] => 1.0000
                )

        )

    [Robert Ngia] => Array
        (
            [mtk004] => Array
                (
                    [100000051] => 6.0000
                    [100000051-1] => 6.0000
                )

            [wbk012] => Array
                (
                    [100000051] => 1.0000
                    [100000051-1] => 1.0000
                )

        )
)
```

get size of array of SKU as a key, you will get the count

Answer (score 1):

well if you are interested in direct query then below is direct query

```
SELECT COUNT( `product_id`),`product_id` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` group by `product_id`
```

If you wanna do from collection way then below is the collection

```
$salesModel=Mage::getModel("sales/order_item")
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('product_id','count(product_id) ')
            ->getCollection();
$salesModel->getSelect()->group('product_id');
```